# How to merge two Arrays/Json with special conditions - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

i need to combine two jsons in a job task, according to the person's location. I have a Json with people from location type 1, and another from location type 2.
I need to combine in a new array for each time they have the same location, and they are repeated and separate according to type. I tried to do it with a foreach inside the other, but with no success. Here is an example of JSON.
Json 1:

```
    [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Jacob",
        "place": "Brazil",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Izac",
        "place": "Brazil",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Anran",
        "place": "Brazil",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Irbur",
        "place": "Brazil",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Lusos",
        "place": "Brazil",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Gamio",
        "place": "Brazil",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Nubeil",
        "place": "Brazil",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Usgon",
        "place": "Brazil",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Fikis",
        "place": "England",
        "type": 1
    }
]
```

Json 2:

```
    [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Gipin",
            "place": "Brazil",
            "type": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Paoir",
            "place": "Brazil",
            "type": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "cia": "Mutue",
            "place": "Brazil",
            "type": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Ziefel",
            "place": "England",
            "type": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "name": "Liedo",
            "place": "England",
            "type": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "name": "Vicis",
            "place": "England",
            "type": 0
        }
]
```

the result might look something like this:

```
{
    "groups": [ // groups (same place)
        {
            "tipe1": [ // groups type 1: same place
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Jacob",
                    "place": "Brazil"
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Jacob",
                    "place": "Brazil"
                }
            ]
            "tipe2": [ // groups type 2: same place
            {
                    "id": 11,
                    "name": "Mutue",
                    "place": "Brazil"
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "tipe1": [ 
                {
                    "id": 15,
                    "name": "Fikis",
                    "place": "England"
                }
            ]
            "tipe2": [
                {
                    "id": 14,
                    "name": "Vicis",
                    "place": "England"
                },
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

The rule for grouping is, two or more items of type 1 can be grouped with 1 of type 2, in reverse as well. It can be thought of as outward flights, and back flights.

Comment: You should post your attempt, and show what research have you done on this topic and what problem you are facing with your attempts.

Comment: I tried to do it in different ways, but it didn't work. The most I got was to group two types, but I always repeat the first type. That's why I asked for help, it's something new I've never done.